# In Event Bubbling, how would you select an element by ID?

Tags: javascript, html, event-handling

How would one select an `e.target` by ID? For instance, you can select an event target by classlist, like `e.target.classList.contains('test')`, but I can't find any way to select an id like `e.target.Id.contains('ID')`.

Am I going about this wrong? Should I instead declare a variable like: `const testVariable = document.querySelector(#id);` and then declare that the `e.target`?

Thanks for any help, I just can't find any documentation on how to declare the event target as an ID.

Comment: Use `e.target.id` not `e.target.Id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'id' is unique hence contains cannot be executed on ids where as there could be multiple classes assigned to a an element so contains work for classes not ids.

Also, as mentioned above the correct syntax is `event.target.id`

Comment: Follow up question: when using `event.target.id('text')` I get a typeError. When using `event.target.id = "test"`, It's setting the ID, not getting the ID. What am I doing wrong? Edit: nevermind, I solved it by `event.target.id =='test'`. Thank you!